# Trying to run each_index on an array but getting `each': can't iterate from NilClass (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

I am currently attempting the codewars 6th kyu kata "Equal Sides Of An Array" where it asks:

'Input:
An integer array of length 0 < arr < 1000. The numbers in the array can be any integer positive or negative.

Output:
The lowest index N where the side to the left of N is equal to the side to the right of N. If you do not find an index that fits these rules, then you will return -1.

Note:
If you are given an array with multiple answers, return the lowest correct index.'

I know my code doesn't work completely but trying to run the code to see where it is going wrong to try and get a further understanding of how to use error codes to guide my thought process.

My code is as follows

```
def find_even_index(arr)
  even_index = -1
  arr.with_each_index do |n, index|
    even_index = index if (arr[0]..arr[index - 1]).sum == (arr[index + 1]..arr[-1]).sum
  end
  even_index
end
```

When I input this into the kata to test, I get the following error:

'./lib/solution.rb:4:in `each': can't iterate from NilClass (TypeError)'

This error leads me to believe that there is an issue with the use of each_with_index on arr but the parameter is an array. What is going wrong here?

Comment: I didn't initially understand that "The lowest index N where the side to the left of N is equal to the side to the right of N" was referring to *sums of values*:   It would be clearer to say, "The smallest index N for which the sum of the elements with indices less than N equals the sum of the elements with indices greater than N".

Comment: Hi there, sorry it is not my wording, it is the wording of the Kata on codewars. I just copied the instructions provided as those are what I was following

Answer (score 1):

There is not `with_each_index` in Ruby, only `each_with_index`

Your problem is in `arr[index + 1]..arr[-1]` on last index

`arr[index + 1]` in that case is `nil` so you tries `nil..arr[-1]`

That's why you have `can't iterate from NilClass (TypeError)` error

You don't need to use ranges in your solution, just use subarrays, array also have [`sum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sum) method

So you can use `each_index` method here like this:

```
def find_even_index(ary)
  ary.each_index do |idx|
    return idx if ary[...idx].sum == ary[idx + 1..].sum
  end

  -1
end

find_even_index([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1])
# => 3

find_even_index([1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1])
# => -1
```

This solution with beginless (available in Ruby >= 2.7) and endless (available in Ruby >= 2.6) ranges

In earlier versions you can use `ary[0...idx]` and `ary[idx + 1..-1]`

Comment: Thank you for this, this is really helpful! With the with_each_index part, that was definitely an error on my part, I had done it as each_index then changed it to what I thought was each_with_index as I thought that could be the issue but obviously typed it while rushing. *doh*. It's a good reminder to be more thorough. It's good to know that I wasn't too far off on the idea and very useful to know that I can use subarrays like that, as am new to coding. Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that does not repeatedly sum each side of a partitioned array.

Note that the Kata defines the sum of the elements before the first and after the last to equal zero.

```
def doit(arr)
  left = 0
  right = arr.sum - arr[0]
  (0..arr.size-1).each do |i|
    return i if left == right
    return -1 if i == arr.size - 1
    left += arr[i]
    right -= arr[i+1]
  end
end
```

```
doit [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  #=> 3
doit [1, 2, 3, -5]
  #=> 0
doit [1, -3, 2, 18]
  #=> 3
doit [99]
  #=> 0
doit [0,0,0,0,0]
  #=> 0
doit [1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  #=> -1
```

---

I can best explain the calculations by executing the method after having salted it with `puts` statements.

```
def doit(arr)
  puts "arr.size == #{arr.size}, arr.sum = #{arr.sum}" 
  left = 0
  right = arr.sum - arr[0]
  puts "initially left = 0, right = #{right}"       
  (0..arr.size-1).each do |i|
    puts "i = #{i}"
    puts left == right ?
      "returning #{i} because left == right" : "left != right"
    return i if left == right       
    puts  i == arr.size - 1 ? "  i == arr.size - 1 so returning #{-1}" :
       "  i < arr.size - 1, so continuing"
    return -1 if i == arr.size - 1
    left += arr[i]
    puts "  left = left + arr[#{i}] = #{left} for i = #{i+1}"
    right -= arr[i+1]
    puts "  right = right - arr[#{i+1}] = #{right} for i = #{i+1}"
  end
end
```

```
doit [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
  #=> 3
```

```
arr.size == 7, arr.sum = 16
initially left = 0, right = 15
i = 0
left != right
  i < arr.size - 1, so continuing
  left = left + arr[0] = 1 for i = 1
  right = right - arr[1] = 13 for i = 1
i = 1
left != right
  i < arr.size - 1, so continuing
  left = left + arr[1] = 3 for i = 2
  right = right - arr[2] = 10 for i = 2
i = 2
left != right
  i < arr.size - 1, so continuing
  left = left + arr[2] = 6 for i = 3
  right = right - arr[3] = 6 for i = 3
i = 3
returning 3 because left == right
```

Comment: I assume this is so that the code runs quicker? Sorry if that's obvious I'm a new coder. I have also input your code into the codewars kata and it fails on the following test: 'Test.assert_equals(find_even_index([0,0,0,0,0]),0,"Should pick the first index if more cases are valid")'

Comment: Chris, yes, the code should be faster than continually summing arrays. I looked up the exact wording of the problem and learned that index zero is correct if the sum of elements of the array minus the first element is zero, meaning that they are defining the sum of an empty collection (the elements left of the element with index zero) to be zero. I'll fix it in about 8 hours, after sleep. You could try to fix it yourself in the interim.

Comment: Hi Cary, sorry I am trying to read your code but am struggling to understand each of the steps that you have taken and therefore am unable to fix the code myself. Again, may just be because I am new to all of this. I get the variables being set at the top. Why have you set (1..arr.size-2)? I get that in the find loop you are adding the previous element iterated to left and removing the current element from the right and you are checking if left==right. My confusion lies with why you have set the variable n and why n = previous element of the array. Is that returning n if left==right is true?

Comment: I revised my answer. Please let me know if it passes all tests.

Comment: Cary, that did pass all tests! Thank you for the breakdown, I found it much easier to read this time. Appreciate all the effort you put in, thank you